# mongoTemplate.findAll() throws exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a problem when I'm trying to use mongoTemplate.findAll() method. Here is a stacktrace of an exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.io.File using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.io.File.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:294)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2105)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1789)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(MongoTemplate.java:1206)
    at com.ub.geopoints_test.tracks.services.TracksGeopointsService.findAllTracks(TracksGeopointsService.java:112)
    at com.ub.geopoints_test.dots.services.MySaxParser.setUpMySaxParser(MySaxParser.java:42)
    at com.ub.geopoints_test.tracks.controllers.TracksGeopointsController.tracks(TracksGeopointsController.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the code where I'm using the findAll() method:

```
@Service
public class MySaxParser extends DefaultHandler{
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
@Autowired
private TracksGeopointsService tracksGeopointsService;

private List<DotGeopointsDoc> dotGeopointsDocList;
private String xmlFileName;
private String tmpValue;
private DotGeopointsDoc dotGeopointsDoc;
private TracksGeopointsDoc tracksGeopointsDoc = new TracksGeopointsDoc();

public void setUpMySaxParser(String bookXmlFileName, File file) {
    this.xmlFileName = bookXmlFileName;
    dotGeopointsDocList = new ArrayList<DotGeopointsDoc>();
    dotGeopointsDoc = new DotGeopointsDoc();
    List<TracksGeopointsDoc> tracks = tracksGeopointsService.findAllTracks(); // Here I get an exception above.
    if (tracks.size() != 0) {
        tracksGeopointsDoc = mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("file").is(file)), TracksGeopointsDoc.class);
    }
    parseDocument();
}
// ....
// some other code
```

And this is my TrackGeopointsDoc class:

```
@Document
public class TracksGeopointsDoc {

@Id
private ObjectId id;

private List<DotGeopointsDoc> dots = new ArrayList<DotGeopointsDoc>();
private File file;

public ObjectId getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(ObjectId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<DotGeopointsDoc> getDots() {
    return dots;
}

public void setDots(List<DotGeopointsDoc> dots) {
    this.dots = dots;
}

public File getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}
}
```

Please, could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That exceptions mean your code couldn't find no-arg constructor for `java.io.File` (because there isn't one).

My suspicion lies on the `private File file` property of `TracksGeopointsDoc`. I don't think that's how you store file in MongoDB, by default each document size is limited at around 16mb.

You either have to store your file as serialized string (bear in mind the document limit), or use [GridFS as recommended in the doc.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)